# Unable to cascade multiple checkbox items

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using the below code to cascade my checkbox list items. My problem when I select one checkbox cascade workds and when I select more than one checkbox cascading is not working. Is there any problem with the comma seperated values?

```
protected void cblGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedValues = string.Empty;
        foreach (ListItem item in cblGroup.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
                selectedValues += item.Value + ",";
        }
        if (selectedValues != string.Empty)
            selectedValues = selectedValues.Remove(selectedValues.Length - 1);
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        con.Open();      
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [Code] from Details where [Group] in ('" + selectedValues + "')", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        cblCode.DataSource = ds;
        cblCode.DataTextField = "Code";
        cblCode.DataValueField = "Code";
        cblCode.DataBind();                   
    }
```

Comment: can you create a string local variable witch is the constructed sql and to print the value in debug console? Then you can test the SQL directly and know if the problem is in the SQL or in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add quotes to all your selectedValues. Try this :

`selectedValues += "'" + item.Value + "',";`

And then use IN as SpaceBison said.

```
protected void cblGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValues = string.Empty;
    foreach (ListItem item in cblGroup.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
            selectedValues += "'" + item.Value + "',";
    }
    if (selectedValues != string.Empty)
        selectedValues = selectedValues.Remove(selectedValues.Length - 1);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    con.Open();      
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [Code] from Details where [Group] in (" + selectedValues + ")", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    cblCode.DataSource = ds;
    cblCode.DataTextField = "Code";
    cblCode.DataValueField = "Code";
    cblCode.DataBind();                   
}
```

Comment: I am bit confused to frame query using this. Could you pls detail me?

Comment: What are confused about? Using IN or constructing the query?

Comment: constructing the query.

Comment: You're constructing your query like this : in ('Item1, Item2'). But all your items have to be between simple quotes, like this : in ('Item1', 'Item2'). So while appending your items with commas, just add the needed quotes

Comment: I added this line of code selectedValues += "'" + item.Value + "'," and my item is disclosed within " " and not like ' '

Comment: This is effectively a copy of my answer, why does it have votes and mine doesn't? :|

Comment: Sorry, he had problems with the quotes and I couldn't comment your answer. I had to answer :/

Comment: Ok that makes sense - Don't worry, I'm just a compulsive moaner :)

Comment: Now my query is formed like this select [Code] from Details where [Group] in ("Item1','Item2")

Comment: Do not add the simple quotes inside the parenthesis : "... in (" + selectedValues + ")"

Comment: like this? "select [Code] from Details where [Group] in (" + selectedValues + ")", con

Comment: It works fine, but when I uncheck values I get an error mentioning Syntax error near')'

Comment: Check that selectedValues isn't empty when selecting **where [Group] in (...)**. If it is empty select all the datas : **select [Code] from Details**

Answer (score 2):

Do you not need to use the SQL `IN` keyword, rather than `=` - since your query is working on comma separated values?

e.g. `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [COL] IN ('1','2','3')`

When only 1 item is selected, there won't be any commas in the where clause, so the query works fine - when more are selected, the query returns no results.

Using `IN` will also work when a single item is selected.

Comment: Like this? SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [Code] from Details where [Group] in ('" + selectedValues + "')", con);

Comment: Still it's the same:(

Comment: If I select more than one checkbox then its respective items are not coming up in the second checkbox. It works fine when one checkbox is selected.

Comment: This is how my query is formed when I select more than one checkbox. So probably the problem is with the comma seperated values. select [Code] from Details where [Group] in ('Item1,Item2')

Comment: @user3003821 - you need quotes around each item, e.g. `IN ('1','2')` as per my example! There's no difference between 'Item1,Item2' and what you had originally, in terms of what SQL will return.